# git checkout <branchname> not working for specific branch

Tags: git, ssh, putty, git-checkout

I have created a repository in bitbucket for educational purposes. I have master and 2 branches.

I have  my droplet on digitalocean, where I entered `git clone` into Putty.

`git checkout <branchname>` works only for one of the branches, and doesn't work for the other. (strange, right?)

if I enter the `git checkout hashtag` of that branch, it works though.

I don't get any error or any message, it just says .. *switched to branch* .. but the result is an early version of master.

Comment: Branches, in Git, mean much less than you think. More precisely, branch *names* mean almost nothing. They just keep track of a particular commit. They do have a sort of automatic update feature as well, but it doesn't work the way I think you think it works...

Answer (score 0):

Seems like this branch has been merged in to master some time in the past, and master has continued moving forwards since. Thus, when you check out that branch, you return to an earlier version of master, when the branch was just merged to it.